# Number of Facebook likes different when connected or not connected

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a recent problem on my website (due to 7th November Breaking changes maybe ?)
Here it is :
When I'm connected to Facebook, I can see the real number of Facebook likes of the page (2,2K).
When I'm not connected to Facebook, I only see 830 likes on this same page...

If I decide to click on, Facebook ask me to connect, I do, and it likes my page, and the number turns to 2,2K...

Someone can help me to explain that ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a URL of the behavior?  Are you using the "like" HTML5 plugin or is this the actual Facebook page url?  What happens when you open your page url in an incognito window?

The behavior you see could be due to a few reasons.

1) The URL used by the like plugin changes slightly when connected. Be sure the use a canonical URL.

2) Some kind of privacy setting. Try using the Facebook Graph API Explorer.  Query for your page without an access token, and then with a valid access token.  Is there any difference from what you are seeing with the plugin?
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

3) A Facebook bug. It's been known to happen, try looking in their bug database:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: Here is the url : [Website](http://www.woozgo.fr)

I'm using the like HTML5 :)
It happens the same thing when I'm in an incognito window.

1) From what I see, the canonical URL is the same when connected or not =/

2) When I query my page in the explorer plugin, I have the same result with or without valid access token :

`{
  "id": "http://www.woozgo.fr",
  "shares": 2083
}`

3) I didn't find any bug like mine in their bug website, i already searched in that :)

Thanks again for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

I opened a bug in Facebook bug website :

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/298333143611066